# Replace a text using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to replace a text using JQuery. but it's replacing with duplicate text.

I have tried below code:

**HTML Code**

```
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
<br>
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
<br>
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var text = $('[class="text_div"]').text();
  var new_text = text.replace("contains", "hello everyone");  
  $('[class="text_div"]').text(new_text);
});
```

**Resulted OUT Put**

```
This div hello everyone some text. This div contains some text. This div contains some text. 
This div hello everyone some text. This div contains some text. This div contains some text. 
This div hello everyone some text. This div contains some text. This div contains some text.
```

**Expecting Out Put**

```
This div hello everyone some text.
This div hello everyone some text. 
This div hello everyone some text.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this

```
  $('.text_div').each(function(x){
    var new_text = $(this).text().replace("contains", "hello everyone"); 
    $(this).text(new_text);
  })
```

for the question in the comment try:

```
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains - some text.
</a>
  $('.text_div').each(function(x){
        var new_text = $(this).text().split('-'); 
        $(this).html(new_text[0]+'span style="color:red;font:bold;">'+new_text[1]+'</span>');
      })
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. If text **This div contains - some text** after `-` text should be like `color = red or font Bold`. how?

Comment: use a span with a class that has your required style and wrap the text in it and then use html instad of text to append it to the page

Comment: @magentotwo Is this answer better than my answer that you marked it?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to get text of all `.text_div` element and change it.

Use jquery [`.text( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to changing text of element one by one.

```js
$(".text_div").text(function(index, text){
    return text.replace("contains", "hello everyone");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
<br>
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
<br>
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
```

Also you can use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method to do this work.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. If text **This div contains - some text** after `-` text should be like `color = red or font Bold`. how?

Comment: after `-` text display style like red.

Comment: @magentotwo This code replace `contains` to `hello everyone` and doesn't relate to another text.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple divs try a loop

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('[class="text_div"]').each(function(i,v){
    var text =$(v).text();
  var new_text = text.replace("contains", "hello everyone");  
  $(v).text(new_text);
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. If text **This div contains - some text** after `-` text should be like `color = red or font Bold`. how?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you can use a class selector to get the elements, instead of a much slower (comparatively) attribute selector: `$('.text_div')`.

Your actual issue is because you are selecting all the elements together, hence the `text()` method returns the text of all elements in a single string. To fix this you could loop through each element individually, using `each()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text_div').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace("contains", "hello everyone");
        $(this).text(text);
    });
});
```

Better still would be to provide a function to the `text()` method which is executed against each element in the matched set:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text_div').text(function(i, t) {
        return t.replace("contains", "hello everyone");
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.text_div').text(function(i, t) {
    return t.replace("contains", "hello everyone");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
<br>
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
<br>
<a class="text_div">
    This div contains some text.
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. If text **This div contains - some text** after `-` text should be like `color = red or font Bold`. how?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test the code, but it seems

> var text = $('[class="text_div"]').text();
>   must return the text for all three  elements... (eg the input will repeat three times so the output will as well)