# How to replace text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using portfolio on one of my website's page, and there is a **SHOW ALL** span attribute which is default by portfolio and shows the photos of any category.
I want to replace the text with jQuery with a custom js plugin.
I tried this code but it changes the text after refreshing the page. Any ideas?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var content=“ΟΛΑ“;
  $(“.qodef-pl-filter-holder ul li.qodef-pl-current span”).html(content); 
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery if div contains this text, replace that part of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324559/jquery-if-div-contains-this-text-replace-that-part-of-the-text)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace a text using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052211/replace-a-text-using-jquery)

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal well,it chaned the name by after i reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content = "ΟΛΑ";
    $(".qodef-pl-filter-holder ul li.qodef-pl-current span").html(content);
});
```

I think it would be better to give the span a class or id to refer to it easier. So something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content = "ΟΛΑ";
    $(".show-all-span").html(content);
});
```